# Is there an easy way to migrate from thunderbird to evolution?

Tags: thunderbird, evolution

I want to be able to use the calendar evolution: the calendar in Thunderbird is a plugin (Lightning) and from time to time when Thunderbird receives a new update, Lightning does not always update automatically as well. So I wanted to have it native in GNOME.

Can anyone explain to me how to do this?

Comment: Are you just using a local calendar, or backend calendar server such as CalDAV?

Comment: local calendar....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export the calendar data from Thunderbird in iCal format. Thunderbird understands this ([link](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/faq.html#apple)) as does Evolution ([link](http://library.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/import-supported-file-formats.html.en)). You [might](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/1312/solved-evolution-cant-import-ics-calendar) need to update to a newer version of Evolution for this to work, due to improvements in the iCal data store manager component of Evolution.

The situation is the same for your mail data, except that you'll want to use `mbox` format in all likelihood.

On the tiny chance that the `mbox` transfer doesn't work properly — very tiny, since `mbox` is one of the oldest, simplest, most well-understood file formats in existence — you could try [migrating Thunderbird to Maildir format](http://jaisejames.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/to-activate-maildir-in-thunderbird/) first, then importing from that. But again, I doubt you'll need to go to such lengths.

Comment: your answer work for mbox , evolution milestone 3.x stores according to Maildir.